# Regarding the number of isomorphisms between splitting fields

Tags: field-theory, induction, splitting-field, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $\phi : F \rightarrow F_1$ be an isomophism of fields and $f(x)
> > \in F[x]$.
>
> Let $\Phi : F[x] \rightarrow F_1[x]$ be the unique ring isomorphism
>   which extends $\phi$ and maps $x$ to $x$.
>
> Let $f_1(x) = \Phi(f(x))$ and $E/F$, $E_1/F_1$ be the splitting fields
>   of $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ respectively.
>
> Then there exists an isomorphism $\gamma : E \rightarrow E_1$ which
>   extends $\phi$.

I wish to prove that the number of such $\gamma \leq [E:F]$.

My intuition is to use induction on $[E:F]$. Furthermore the proof for the above theorem uses the same induction strategy.

In the base case $[E:F] = 1$ and $\gamma$ must map the single root of $f(x)$ to the single root of $f_1(x)$, so there can only be a single isomorphism $\gamma$.

Considering the case $[E:F] = 2$, I notice that strict equality holds if (and only if?) $f$ is seperable.

I'm not sure how to proceed with the inductive step. Is this approach using induction on $[E:F]$ even correct? If so, what's the right direction to apply the inductive step?